# How to make Docker container and the host on same Network Level?

Tags: networking, docker, docker-for-windows

I want to make docker container's IP accessible from the host, just like "Host-only network" that VirtualBox has.

Currently I can ping the windows host from docker container, but not the other way around.

This is my Docker container configuration

```
/ # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:02
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2091 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:176077 (171.9 KiB)  TX bytes:3396902 (3.2 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:444 (444.0 B)  TX bytes:444 (444.0 B)
```

This is the windows host

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9197:4f9c:c12b:a2d4%29
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.18.0.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

This is the result when I tried to ping Windows host from container

```
/ # ping  172.18.0.1
PING 172.18.0.1 (172.18.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: seq=0 ttl=37 time=1.369 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: seq=1 ttl=37 time=1.580 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: seq=2 ttl=37 time=1.524 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: seq=3 ttl=37 time=1.416 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: seq=4 ttl=37 time=1.573 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.1: seq=5 ttl=37 time=1.428 ms
```

Comment: I don't think this can be accomplished with Docker Desktop. But maybe that’s not what you’re using? Please provide more details.

Comment: @DanielB Sadly yes. Is there any alternative I can try on?

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you need to reach a certain service at a certain port? In that case you need to [publish that port](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports). Alternatively you can set the network mode [to `host`](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/), which let's the docker container use the network of the host directly. Please [edit] your question to include some info on your final goal.